# Incorrect syntax near 'CAST' ,what should I do

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    TerritoryID,
    COUNT (SalesOrderID) AS Total_orders 
    CAST (SUM(TotalDue) AS INT) 'Total sales amount'
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE 
    Total_orders > 3500
```

I tried to run this code, but always give me an error like this:

> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.

Comment: comma after Total_Orders

Comment: Welcome on SO, please add a tag with your used DBMS (Sql Server, MySql, Oracle and so on)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Also: using string constants (`'Total sales month'`) as identifiers is invalid standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT TerritoryID,
    COUNT (SalesOrderID) AS Total_orders,
    CAST (SUM(TotalDue) AS INT) AS Total_sales_amount
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader S
   GROUP BY S.TerritoryID
   HAVING COUNT (SalesOrderID) > 3500
```

Something like this

Answer (score 1):

Waiting to mark your question with correct DBMS.

I see three major errors:

- you have missed a comma after Total_orders
- you haven't use a GROUP BY statement about TerritoryID
- you haven't use HAVING instead WHERE

Another possible is the absence of AS before 'Total sales amount' and a potentially the use of single quote instead of double quote (it depends by used DBMS)

```
SELECT TerritoryID,
COUNT (SalesOrderID) AS Total_orders, <-----
CAST (SUM(TotalDue) AS INT) 'Total sales amount'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
GROUP BY TerritoryID
HAVING COUNT (SalesOrderID) > 3500
```

Comment: Also note that the column alias should have double quotes.  It's an identifier, not a string literal.